# Create /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/2021-08-19/logstart-.1629387459287.gz.tmp, but there is no such file in hdfs

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, flume

I'm using flume to get data from Kafka to HDFS. (Kafka Source and HDFS Sink). These are the versions I'm using.

```
hadoop-3.2.2
flume-1.9.0
kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0
```

This is my kafka-fluem-hdfs.conf:

```
a1.sources=r1 r2
a1.channels=c1 c2
a1.sinks=k1 k2

## source1
a1.sources.r1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
a1.sources.r1.batchSize = 5000
a1.sources.r1.batchDurationMillis = 2000
a1.sources.r1.kafka.bootstrap.servers=h01:9092,h02:9092,h03:9092
a1.sources.r1.kafka.topics=topic_start

## source2
a1.sources.r2.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
a1.sources.r2.batchSize = 5000
a1.sources.r2.batchDurationMillis = 2000
a1.sources.r2.kafka.bootstrap.servers=h01:9092,h02:9092,h03:9092
a1.sources.r2.kafka.topics=topic_event


## channel1
a1.channels.c1.type = file
a1.channels.c1.checkpointDir=/usr/local/flume/checkpoint/behavior1
a1.channels.c1.dataDirs = /usr/local/flume/data/behavior1/
a1.channels.c1.keep-alive = 6
## channel2
a1.channels.c2.type = file
a1.channels.c2.checkpointDir=/usr/local/flume/checkpoint/behavior2
a1.channels.c2.dataDirs = /usr/local/flume/data/behavior2/
a1.channels.c2.keep-alive = 6

## sink1
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/%Y-%m-%d
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = logstart-
##sink2
a1.sinks.k2.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.path = /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_event/%Y-%m-%d
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.filePrefix = logevent-


a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval = 10
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollSize = 134217728
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollInterval = 10
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollSize = 134217728
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollCount = 0

a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = CompressedStream
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.fileType = CompressedStream


a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.codeC = gzip
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.codeC = gzip

#a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.codeC=com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
#a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat=Text
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.callTimeout=360000
#a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.maxIoWorkers=32
#a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileSuffix=.lzo


#a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.codeC=com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
#a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.writeFormat=Text
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.callTimeout=360000
#a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.maxIoWorkers=32
#a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.fileSuffix=.lzo




a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel= c1

a1.sources.r2.channels = c2
a1.sinks.k2.channel= c2
```

The part of the log file:

```
2021-08-19 15:37:39,308 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:open(246)) - Creating /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/2021-08-19/logstart-.1629387459287.gz.tmp
2021-08-19 15:37:40,476 INFO  [hdfs-k1-call-runner-0] zlib.ZlibFactory (ZlibFactory.java:loadNativeZLib(59)) - Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
2021-08-19 15:37:40,509 INFO  [hdfs-k1-call-runner-0] compress.CodecPool (CodecPool.java:getCompressor(153)) - Got brand-new compressor [.gz]
2021-08-19 15:37:40,516 INFO  [hdfs-k1-call-runner-0] hdfs.AbstractHDFSWriter (AbstractHDFSWriter.java:reflectGetNumCurrentReplicas(190)) - FileSystem's output stream doesn't support getNumCurrentReplicas; --HDFS-826 not available; fsOut=org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer; err=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.getNumCurrentReplicas()
2021-08-19 15:37:40,525 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:getRefIsClosed(197)) - isFileClosed() is not available in the version of the distributed filesystem being used. Flume will not attempt to re-close files if the close fails on the first attempt
2021-08-19 15:37:40,522 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:open(246)) - Creating /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_event/2021-08-19/logevent-.1629387459287.gz.tmp
2021-08-19 15:37:40,858 INFO  [hdfs-k2-call-runner-0] compress.CodecPool (CodecPool.java:getCompressor(153)) - Got brand-new compressor [.gz]
2021-08-19 15:37:40,889 INFO  [hdfs-k2-call-runner-0] hdfs.AbstractHDFSWriter (AbstractHDFSWriter.java:reflectGetNumCurrentReplicas(190)) - FileSystem's output stream doesn't support getNumCurrentReplicas
```

**my problems:

Create /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/2021-08-19/logstart-.1629387459287.gz.tmp, but there is no such file in hdfs.**

More logs after I start flume:

```
....
....
....

2021-08-19 15:30:01,748 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile (EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:beginCheckpoint(230)) - Start checkpoint for /usr/local/flume/checkpoint/behavior1/checkpoint, elements to sync = 0
2021-08-19 15:30:01,754 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-1] file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile (EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:checkpoint(255)) - Updating checkpoint metadata: logWriteOrderID: 1629387001047, queueSize: 0, queueHead: 5765
2021-08-19 15:30:01,758 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile (EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:checkpoint(255)) - Updating checkpoint metadata: logWriteOrderID: 1629387001048, queueSize: 0, queueHead: 5778
2021-08-19 15:30:01,783 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] file.Log (Log.java:writeCheckpoint(1065)) - Updated checkpoint for file: /usr/local/flume/data/behavior1/log-26 position: 0 logWriteOrderID: 1629387001048
2021-08-19 15:30:01,783 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] file.FileChannel (FileChannel.java:start(289)) - Queue Size after replay: 0 [channel=c1]
2021-08-19 15:30:01,784 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-1] file.Log (Log.java:writeCheckpoint(1065)) - Updated checkpoint for file: /usr/local/flume/data/behavior2/log-26 position: 0 logWriteOrderID: 1629387001047
2021-08-19 15:30:01,787 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-1] file.FileChannel (FileChannel.java:start(289)) - Queue Size after replay: 0 [channel=c2]
2021-08-19 15:30:01,789 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] node.Application (Application.java:startAllComponents(196)) - Starting Sink k1
2021-08-19 15:30:01,795 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:register(119)) - Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: k1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2021-08-19 15:30:01,795 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:start(95)) - Component type: SINK, name: k1 started
2021-08-19 15:30:01,797 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] node.Application (Application.java:startAllComponents(196)) - Starting Sink k2
2021-08-19 15:30:01,798 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] node.Application (Application.java:startAllComponents(207)) - Starting Source r2
2021-08-19 15:30:01,799 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-5] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:register(119)) - Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: k2: Successfully registered new MBean.
2021-08-19 15:30:01,803 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-5] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:start(95)) - Component type: SINK, name: k2 started
2021-08-19 15:30:01,799 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-6] kafka.KafkaSource (KafkaSource.java:doStart(524)) - Starting org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource{name:r2,state:IDLE}...
2021-08-19 15:30:01,815 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] node.Application (Application.java:startAllComponents(207)) - Starting Source r1
2021-08-19 15:30:01,818 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] kafka.KafkaSource (KafkaSource.java:doStart(524)) - Starting org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource{name:r1,state:IDLE}...
2021-08-19 15:30:01,918 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-6] consumer.ConsumerConfig (AbstractConfig.java:logAll(279)) - ConsumerConfig values: 
    ......
.......
.......

2021-08-19 15:30:01,926 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] consumer.ConsumerConfig (AbstractConfig.java:logAll(279)) - ConsumerConfig values: 
    .....
......
......

2021-08-19 15:30:02,210 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] utils.AppInfoParser (AppInfoParser.java:<init>(109)) - Kafka version : 2.0.1
2021-08-19 15:30:02,210 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-6] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:register(119)) - Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: r2: Successfully registered new MBean.
2021-08-19 15:30:02,211 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-6] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:start(95)) - Component type: SOURCE, name: r2 started
2021-08-19 15:30:02,210 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] utils.AppInfoParser (AppInfoParser.java:<init>(110)) - Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2021-08-19 15:30:02,213 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] kafka.KafkaSource (KafkaSource.java:doStart(547)) - Kafka source r1 started.
2021-08-19 15:30:02,214 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:register(119)) - Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: r1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2021-08-19 15:30:02,214 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:start(95)) - Component type: SOURCE, name: r1 started
2021-08-19 15:30:02,726 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] clients.Metadata (Metadata.java:update(285)) - Cluster ID: erHI3p-1SzKgC1ywVUE_Dw
2021-08-19 15:30:02,730 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] clients.Metadata (Metadata.java:update(285)) - Cluster ID: erHI3p-1SzKgC1ywVUE_Dw
2021-08-19 15:30:02,740 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:onSuccess(677)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=flume] Discovered group coordinator h01:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2021-08-19 15:30:02,747 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:onSuccess(677)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] Discovered group coordinator h01:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2021-08-19 15:30:02,748 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (ConsumerCoordinator.java:onJoinPrepare(472)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=flume] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2021-08-19 15:30:02,770 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:sendJoinGroupRequest(509)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=flume] (Re-)joining group
2021-08-19 15:30:02,776 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (ConsumerCoordinator.java:onJoinPrepare(472)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2021-08-19 15:30:02,776 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:sendJoinGroupRequest(509)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] (Re-)joining group
2021-08-19 15:30:02,845 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:sendJoinGroupRequest(509)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] (Re-)joining group
2021-08-19 15:30:02,935 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:onSuccess(473)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=flume] Successfully joined group with generation 66
2021-08-19 15:30:02,936 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (ConsumerCoordinator.java:onJoinComplete(280)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=flume] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic_event-0]
2021-08-19 15:30:02,936 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] kafka.SourceRebalanceListener (KafkaSource.java:onPartitionsAssigned(648)) - topic topic_event - partition 0 assigned.
2021-08-19 15:30:02,950 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:onSuccess(473)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] Successfully joined group with generation 66
2021-08-19 15:30:02,950 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (ConsumerCoordinator.java:onJoinComplete(280)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic_start-0]
2021-08-19 15:30:02,950 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] kafka.SourceRebalanceListener (KafkaSource.java:onPartitionsAssigned(648)) - topic topic_start - partition 0 assigned.
2021-08-19 15:30:04,912 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.HDFSCompressedDataStream (HDFSCompressedDataStream.java:configure(64)) - Serializer = TEXT, UseRawLocalFileSystem = false
2021-08-19 15:30:04,912 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.HDFSCompressedDataStream (HDFSCompressedDataStream.java:configure(64)) - Serializer = TEXT, UseRawLocalFileSystem = false
2021-08-19 15:30:04,984 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:open(246)) - Creating /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_event/2021-08-19/logevent-.1629387004913.gz.tmp
2021-08-19 15:30:06,577 INFO  [hdfs-k2-call-runner-0] zlib.ZlibFactory (ZlibFactory.java:loadNativeZLib(59)) - Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
2021-08-19 15:30:06,606 INFO  [hdfs-k2-call-runner-0] compress.CodecPool (CodecPool.java:getCompressor(153)) - Got brand-new compressor [.gz]
2021-08-19 15:30:06,648 INFO  [hdfs-k2-call-runner-0] hdfs.AbstractHDFSWriter (AbstractHDFSWriter.java:reflectGetNumCurrentReplicas(190)) - FileSystem's output stream doesn't support getNumCurrentReplicas; --HDFS-826 not available; fsOut=org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer; err=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.getNumCurrentReplicas()
2021-08-19 15:30:06,665 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:open(246)) - Creating /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/2021-08-19/logstart-.1629387004913.gz.tmp
2021-08-19 15:30:06,675 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:getRefIsClosed(197)) - isFileClosed() is not available in the version of the distributed filesystem being used. Flume will not attempt to re-close files if the close fails on the first attempt
2021-08-19 15:30:06,916 INFO  [hdfs-k1-call-runner-0] compress.CodecPool (CodecPool.java:getCompressor(153)) - Got brand-new compressor [.gz]
2021-08-19 15:30:06,927 INFO  [hdfs-k1-call-runner-0] hdfs.AbstractHDFSWriter (AbstractHDFSWriter.java:reflectGetNumCurrentReplicas(190)) - FileSystem's output stream doesn't support getNumCurrentReplicas; --HDFS-826 not available; fsOut=org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer; err=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.getNumCurrentReplicas()
2021-08-19 15:30:06,931 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:getRefIsClosed(197)) - isFileClosed() is not available in the version of the distributed filesystem being used. Flume will not attempt to re-close files if the close fails on the first attempt
2021-08-19 15:30:16,676 INFO  [hdfs-k2-roll-timer-0] hdfs.HDFSEventSink (HDFSEventSink.java:run(393)) - Writer callback called.
2021-08-19 15:30:16,676 INFO  [hdfs-k2-roll-timer-0] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:doClose(438)) - Closing /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_event/2021-08-19/logevent-.1629387004913.gz.tmp
2021-08-19 15:30:16,682 INFO  [hdfs-k2-call-runner-2] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:call(681)) - Renaming /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_event/2021-08-19/logevent-.1629387004913.gz.tmp to /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_event/2021-08-19/logevent-.1629387004913.gz
2021-08-19 15:30:16,932 INFO  [hdfs-k1-roll-timer-0] hdfs.HDFSEventSink (HDFSEventSink.java:run(393)) - Writer callback called.
2021-08-19 15:30:16,932 INFO  [hdfs-k1-roll-timer-0] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:doClose(438)) - Closing /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/2021-08-19/logstart-.1629387004913.gz.tmp
2021-08-19 15:30:16,934 INFO  [hdfs-k1-call-runner-2] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:call(681)) - Renaming /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/2021-08-19/logstart-.1629387004913.gz.tmp to /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/2021-08-19/logstart-.1629387004913.gz
2021-08-19 15:30:30,932 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile (EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:beginCheckpoint(230)) - Start checkpoint for /usr/local/flume/checkpoint/behavior2/checkpoint, elements to sync = 970
2021-08-19 15:30:30,936 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c1] file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile (EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:beginCheckpoint(230)) - Start checkpoint for /usr/local/flume/checkpoint/behavior1/checkpoint, elements to sync = 967
2021-08-19 15:30:30,951 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile (EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:checkpoint(255)) - Updating checkpoint metadata: logWriteOrderID: 1629387004945, queueSize: 0, queueHead: 6733
2021-08-19 15:30:30,953 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c1] file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile (EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:checkpoint(255)) - Updating checkpoint metadata: logWriteOrderID: 1629387004946, queueSize: 0, queueHead: 6743
2021-08-19 15:30:30,963 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.Log (Log.java:writeCheckpoint(1065)) - Updated checkpoint for file: /usr/local/flume/data/behavior2/log-26 position: 1147366 logWriteOrderID: 1629387004945
2021-08-19 15:30:30,964 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior2/log-20
2021-08-19 15:30:30,967 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c1] file.Log (Log.java:writeCheckpoint(1065)) - Updated checkpoint for file: /usr/local/flume/data/behavior1/log-26 position: 487027 logWriteOrderID: 1629387004946
.....
.....
.....


2021-08-19 15:36:19,570 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-8] utils.AppInfoParser (AppInfoParser.java:<init>(109)) - Kafka version : 2.0.1
2021-08-19 15:36:19,570 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-8] utils.AppInfoParser (AppInfoParser.java:<init>(110)) - Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2021-08-19 15:36:19,572 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-6] utils.AppInfoParser (AppInfoParser.java:<init>(109)) - Kafka version : 2.0.1
2021-08-19 15:36:19,572 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-6] utils.AppInfoParser (AppInfoParser.java:<init>(110)) - Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2021-08-19 15:36:19,572 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-8] kafka.KafkaSource (KafkaSource.java:doStart(547)) - Kafka source r1 started.
2021-08-19 15:36:19,572 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-6] kafka.KafkaSource (KafkaSource.java:doStart(547)) - Kafka source r2 started.
2021-08-19 15:36:19,573 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-8] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:register(119)) - Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: r1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2021-08-19 15:36:19,573 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-6] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:register(119)) - Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: r2: Successfully registered new MBean.
2021-08-19 15:36:19,573 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-8] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:start(95)) - Component type: SOURCE, name: r1 started
2021-08-19 15:36:19,573 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-6] instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup (MonitoredCounterGroup.java:start(95)) - Component type: SOURCE, name: r2 started
2021-08-19 15:36:20,012 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] clients.Metadata (Metadata.java:update(285)) - Cluster ID: erHI3p-1SzKgC1ywVUE_Dw
2021-08-19 15:36:20,015 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:onSuccess(677)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=flume] Discovered group coordinator h01:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2021-08-19 15:36:20,025 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (ConsumerCoordinator.java:onJoinPrepare(472)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=flume] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2021-08-19 15:36:20,027 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:sendJoinGroupRequest(509)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=flume] (Re-)joining group
2021-08-19 15:36:20,030 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] clients.Metadata (Metadata.java:update(285)) - Cluster ID: erHI3p-1SzKgC1ywVUE_Dw
2021-08-19 15:36:20,034 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:onSuccess(677)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] Discovered group coordinator h01:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2021-08-19 15:36:20,039 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (ConsumerCoordinator.java:onJoinPrepare(472)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2021-08-19 15:36:20,039 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:sendJoinGroupRequest(509)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] (Re-)joining group
2021-08-19 15:36:20,068 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:sendJoinGroupRequest(509)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] (Re-)joining group
2021-08-19 15:36:20,152 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:onSuccess(473)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=flume] Successfully joined group with generation 69
2021-08-19 15:36:20,153 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (ConsumerCoordinator.java:onJoinComplete(280)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=flume] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic_event-0]
2021-08-19 15:36:20,154 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r2] kafka.SourceRebalanceListener (KafkaSource.java:onPartitionsAssigned(648)) - topic topic_event - partition 0 assigned.
2021-08-19 15:36:20,159 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.AbstractCoordinator (AbstractCoordinator.java:onSuccess(473)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] Successfully joined group with generation 69
2021-08-19 15:36:20,159 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] internals.ConsumerCoordinator (ConsumerCoordinator.java:onJoinComplete(280)) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=flume] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic_start-0]
2021-08-19 15:36:20,159 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-r1] kafka.SourceRebalanceListener (KafkaSource.java:onPartitionsAssigned(648)) - topic topic_start - partition 0 assigned.
2021-08-19 15:37:39,286 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.HDFSCompressedDataStream (HDFSCompressedDataStream.java:configure(64)) - Serializer = TEXT, UseRawLocalFileSystem = false
2021-08-19 15:37:39,286 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.HDFSCompressedDataStream (HDFSCompressedDataStream.java:configure(64)) - Serializer = TEXT, UseRawLocalFileSystem = false
2021-08-19 15:37:39,308 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:open(246)) - Creating /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/2021-08-19/logstart-.1629387459287.gz.tmp
2021-08-19 15:37:40,476 INFO  [hdfs-k1-call-runner-0] zlib.ZlibFactory (ZlibFactory.java:loadNativeZLib(59)) - Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
2021-08-19 15:37:40,509 INFO  [hdfs-k1-call-runner-0] compress.CodecPool (CodecPool.java:getCompressor(153)) - Got brand-new compressor [.gz]
2021-08-19 15:37:40,516 INFO  [hdfs-k1-call-runner-0] hdfs.AbstractHDFSWriter (AbstractHDFSWriter.java:reflectGetNumCurrentReplicas(190)) - FileSystem's output stream doesn't support getNumCurrentReplicas; --HDFS-826 not available; fsOut=org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer; err=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.getNumCurrentReplicas()
2021-08-19 15:37:40,525 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:getRefIsClosed(197)) - isFileClosed() is not available in the version of the distributed filesystem being used. Flume will not attempt to re-close files if the close fails on the first attempt
2021-08-19 15:37:40,522 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:open(246)) - Creating /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_event/2021-08-19/logevent-.1629387459287.gz.tmp
2021-08-19 15:37:40,858 INFO  [hdfs-k2-call-runner-0] compress.CodecPool (CodecPool.java:getCompressor(153)) - Got brand-new compressor [.gz]
2021-08-19 15:37:40,889 INFO  [hdfs-k2-call-runner-0] hdfs.AbstractHDFSWriter (AbstractHDFSWriter.java:reflectGetNumCurrentReplicas(190)) - FileSystem's output stream doesn't support getNumCurrentReplicas; --HDFS-826 not available; fsOut=org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer; err=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.getNumCurrentReplicas()
2021-08-19 15:37:40,889 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:getRefIsClosed(197)) - isFileClosed() is not available in the version of the distributed filesystem being used. Flume will not attempt to re-close files if the close fails on the first attempt
2021-08-19 15:37:48,532 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile (EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:beginCheckpoint(230)) - Start checkpoint for /usr/local/flume/checkpoint/behavior2/checkpoint, elements to sync = 949
2021-08-19 15:37:48,533 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c1] file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile (EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:beginCheckpoint(230)) - Start checkpoint for /usr/local/flume/checkpoint/behavior1/checkpoint, elements to sync = 1002
2021-08-19 15:37:48,562 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c1] file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile (EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:checkpoint(255)) - Updating checkpoint metadata: logWriteOrderID: 1629387382580, queueSize: 0, queueHead: 7743
2021-08-19 15:37:48,562 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile (EventQueueBackingStoreFile.java:checkpoint(255)) - Updating checkpoint metadata: logWriteOrderID: 1629387382581, queueSize: 0, queueHead: 7680
2021-08-19 15:37:48,570 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c1] file.Log (Log.java:writeCheckpoint(1065)) - Updated checkpoint for file: /usr/local/flume/data/behavior1/log-27 position: 504908 logWriteOrderID: 1629387382580
2021-08-19 15:37:48,571 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c1] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior1/log-21
2021-08-19 15:37:48,578 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c1] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior1/log-22
2021-08-19 15:37:48,578 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.Log (Log.java:writeCheckpoint(1065)) - Updated checkpoint for file: /usr/local/flume/data/behavior2/log-27 position: 1144058 logWriteOrderID: 1629387382581
2021-08-19 15:37:48,581 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior2/log-20
2021-08-19 15:37:48,585 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c1] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior1/log-23
2021-08-19 15:37:48,587 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior2/log-21
2021-08-19 15:37:48,591 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c1] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior1/log-24
2021-08-19 15:37:48,593 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior2/log-22
2021-08-19 15:37:48,597 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c1] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior1/log-25
2021-08-19 15:37:48,600 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior2/log-23
2021-08-19 15:37:48,606 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior2/log-24
2021-08-19 15:37:48,612 INFO  [Log-BackgroundWorker-c2] file.LogFile (LogFile.java:close(520)) - Closing RandomReader /usr/local/flume/data/behavior2/log-25
2021-08-19 15:37:50,526 INFO  [hdfs-k1-roll-timer-0] hdfs.HDFSEventSink (HDFSEventSink.java:run(393)) - Writer callback called.
2021-08-19 15:37:50,526 INFO  [hdfs-k1-roll-timer-0] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:doClose(438)) - Closing /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/2021-08-19/logstart-.1629387459287.gz.tmp
2021-08-19 15:37:50,694 INFO  [hdfs-k1-call-runner-6] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:call(681)) - Renaming /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/2021-08-19/logstart-.1629387459287.gz.tmp to /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/2021-08-19/logstart-.1629387459287.gz
2021-08-19 15:37:50,890 INFO  [hdfs-k2-roll-timer-0] hdfs.HDFSEventSink (HDFSEventSink.java:run(393)) - Writer callback called.
2021-08-19 15:37:50,890 INFO  [hdfs-k2-roll-timer-0] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:doClose(438)) - Closing /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_event/2021-08-19/logevent-.1629387459287.gz.tmp
2021-08-19 15:37:50,893 INFO  [hdfs-k2-call-runner-3] hdfs.BucketWriter (BucketWriter.java:call(681)) - Renaming /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_event/2021-08-19/logevent-.1629387459287.gz.tmp to /origin_data/gmall/log/topic_event/2021-08-19/logevent-.1629387459287.gz

.......
.......
.......
```

Comment: You'd be getting `NoSuchMethodException` if you are using an HDFS client that is not supported by Flume (such as Hadoop 3.x). Try using 2.9.x... Also note that Kafka 0.10.1 is very old, and Flume includes clients for Kafka 2.0.1

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using Flume compared to Kafka Connect, for example?

Comment: oh, I corrected this error by modifiying 
 
 the```a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path=hdfs://h01:9000/origin_data/gmall/log/topic_start/%Y-%m-%d```in the ```kafka-flume-hdfs.conf```file，where h01 represents the master node of hadoop.

Comment: That'll work as long as that is the active namenode, but you should still fix the client versioning